# WebSphere Portal CoreQueries / PortalLog Warnings

Tags: websphere-portal

Does anyone know what the "CoreQueries" or "PortalLog" references in a WebSphere Portal systemout.log file?

The following are Warnings that are being thrown up and seem to me to be coming from the base installation of the portal itself, rather than the content it refers to.

```
[DATE] 00000101 CoreQueries W Retrieval of obects from repository failed with error/contentRoot/icm:libraries[30]/Content/path/goes/here

[DATE] 00000101 PortletLog W org.apache.jetspeed.portlet.PortletLog warn No content could be found at the path /Content/path/goes/here Please check the path in the config mode.
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a deleted item still being referenced by another content item.
I would suggest tailing the SystemOut.log (tail -f) to see if you are able to track the pages.

Click on the possible problem pages and see if your error appears in the SystemOut.log.

Hope this helps.

Jerome Slinger